# NavigationStack inside NavigationSplitView detail in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationsplitview

I have a typical `NavigationSplitView` layout in my app:

```
NavigationSplitView {
  List(0..<3, selection: $selection) { item in
    Label(MainDataType.data[item].name, systemImage: MainDataType.data[item].icon)
  }
} content: {
  switch selection {
     case 0: StudentsView()
     case 1: WorksView()
// More options here...
  }
} detail: {
  NoDataView() // <- Just for main view first presentation.
}
```

`Sidebar` and `Content` views work perfectly fine. For `Detail` view, I overwrite default `NoDataView` with, for example, `StudentDetail`, from `StudentsView` selection:

```
struct StudentsView() {
...
List(students, id:\.self) { student in
   NavigationLink(destination: NavigationStack { // <- In order to get navigation inside SplitView detail column.
     StudentDetailView(student: student)}) {
       StudentCellView(student: student)
...
```

As in `StudentDetailView` I have deeper `NavigationLinks` (see attached gif).

This layout has been working until iOS17. Now it still works almost in every case, but this console message appears:

> A NavigationLink is presenting a NavigationStack onto a column. This construction is not supported. Consider instead just presenting a new root view which will replace that of an existing stack in the column, or else the column itself if there is no NavigationStack in the target column. If there is a stack in the target column, appending to that stack's path is another option.

I'm testing these navigation changes:

```
struct StudentsView() {
...
  List(students, id:\.self) { student in
    NavigationLink(destination: StudentDetailView(student: student)) {
       StudentCellView(student: student)
...
```

This way no console message is shown, and deep `NavigationLinks` work (more or less), but with no navigation behavior (navigating back, animation...).

So I'm now struggling with this two questions:

- Is there any way of getting a complete full-support `NavigationStack` inside detail view of `NavigationSplitView`?
- If so, what's the code to get it work?
- If not, what are the alternatives?

[image]

Comment: I haven’t combed through the release notes but something changed with NavigationSplitView there used to be an example in the documentation but that example has disappeared I would expect the release notes to say something.

Answer (score 2):

Your example looks a little like the three-column [example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview#overview).

In general, you would want to have your `NavigationStack` as the root view in the `details` part of the split view. Inside the `NavigationStack`, you would then choose which view should be displayed, based on what has been selected in the `content` part. This is exactly what the part in the error message means:

> *Consider instead just presenting a new root view which will replace that of an existing stack in the column*

Here is a minimal example of what I mean:

```swift
struct TestView: View {
    enum ContentSelection: Hashable {
        case one
        case two
    }
    
    @State var contentSelection: ContentSelection?
    @State var columnVisibility: NavigationSplitViewVisibility = .doubleColumn
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: $columnVisibility) {
            List {
                Text("Sidebar one")
            }
        } content: {
            List(selection: $contentSelection) {
                Text("Content one")
                    .tag(ContentSelection.one)
                Text("Content two")
                    .tag(ContentSelection.two)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                switch contentSelection {
                case .one:
                    NavigationLink("ONE") {
                        Text("ONE one level deeper")
                    }
                case .two:
                    NavigationLink("TWO") {
                        Text("TWO one level deeper")
                    }
                case .none:
                    Text("Nothing")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Preview of the example code]

In your case, you would have your students list in the `content` part, but you would need to replace the `NavigationLink`s in the list by using the `List(selection:)` initializer. Based on this selection, you can display the correct student details in the `details` section (inside the `NavigationStack` there).

Also, for deeper navigation hierarchies, you can take a look at [NavigationStack(path:root:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/init(path:root:)-63x0h), which works quite nicely together with the [`NavigationLink(value:label:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(value:label:)-4jswo) and the [`.navigationDestination(for:destination:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationdestination(for:destination:)) modifier. You can just create your own `Destination` enum (make it conform to `Hashable`) and use an array (`[Destination]`) as your `path`.

Comment: Thanks, @vollkorntomate. I understand your explanation, but I need SideBar to have selectable values itself, and due to that selection, ContentView must present different Lists (Students, Works, Rehearsals...)that lists present selectable items, and finally, DetailView must present DetailView for each type . I mean: a level higher. You can see it on my gif: SideBar contains the list of content types of my app, ContentView, the list of each type items, and DetailView all related information for that item, with its own deeper NavigationLinks.

Comment: ...So main problem here is that `NavigationSplitView`'s `DetailView` can contain ins my app heterogeneous types of data, so Apple explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationsplitview) can't be applied directly.

Answer (score 0):

Voila! I have found the problem. So simple: just embedding `detail:` column content itself in a `NavigationStack`.

```
NavigationSplitView {
  List(0..<3, selection: $selection) { item in
    Label(MainDataType.data[item].name, systemImage: MainDataType.data[item].icon)
  }
} content: {
  switch selection {
     case 0: StudentsView()
     case 1: WorksView()
// More options here...
  }
} detail: {
  NavigationStack {  // <- Here!
     NoDataView()
  }
}
```

Despite `detail:` content is being in fact defined on intermediate views, this way general `NavigationSplitView` outline seems to keep its behavior app-wide. So does every *stack of views* displayed on `detail:` column.